# How to download video (mp4) file in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I uploaded video to Firebase Storage and want to download and save it to local storage. I used [gallery_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver) plugin for download video from network but it gives me exception.

```
 GallerySaver.saveVideo(url, albumName: "ABC/Videos");
```

Exception.

```
E/flutter ( 9221): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): File on path is not a video.
E/flutter ( 9221): #0      GallerySaver.saveVideo (package:gallery_saver/gallery_saver.dart:27:7)
E/flutter ( 9221): #1      _OptionSelectionState.saveToLocale (package:pixz_app/ui/widgets/options_view.dart:618:22)
E/flutter ( 9221): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Is there any other plugin or method for download video from firebase video(mp4) url.

[Video Link](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pixz-92afa.appspot.com/o/PostVideos%2F0xb159d1586689312896%2F0xb159d15866893128961586846213136_video?alt=media&token=af6b076b-405e-4763-abb4-69a83f92d15b)

Comment: Provide please url that you're trying to use

Comment: Please check I added video URL

Answer (score 0):

Flutter `gallery saver` works only with direct resource URL. So you better use [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/)/ [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) / other storage service.

Answer (score 0):

for downloading a file I recommend using the Dio package. as document Dio is:

> A powerful Http client for Dart, which supports Interceptors, Global
>   configuration, FormData, Request Cancellation, File downloading,
>   Timeout etc.

Dio will save the file after it has been downloaded.

this is a simple code for downloading a file with Dio:

```
final response = await dio.download(url, savePath);
```

for more complicated example check this links;

1. [download file](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/example/download.dart).
2. [download with trunks](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/example/download_with_trunks.dart)

Answer (score -1):

One way you can do it, is by using the URL Launcher to open the link and let the device browser handle the download.

Add the following to your pubspec

```
url_launcher: ^5.4.2
```

Import it

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

_launchURL(string url) async {

  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

then just call the method on your url

```
RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Landscape Left"),
              onPressed: () async {
              await _launchURL('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pixz-92afa.appspot.com/o/PostVideos%2F0xb159d1586689312896%2F0xb159d15866893128961586846213136_video?alt=media&token=af6b076b-405e-4763-abb4-69a83f92d15b'); // your URL 
            });
```

#### References

1. [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)